# Batch FTP mget command not working with wildcard?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch script that logs into my ftp server, then navigates to a directory. I am having trouble with the mget command, I want it to download every .dat file in the directory, but it simply returns this error:

```
Cannot access file '/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server267/world/players/*.dat':No such file or directory.
200 Type set to: ANSI
Cannot find list of remote files
```

Here is my script (ran from cmd)

```
open 66.71.244.202
USER
PASSWORD
cd /world
cd players
mget *.dat
```

Comment: Does it work when you run the commands manually, rather than from a batch file?

Comment: Can you list your target files in that directory?

Comment: Along the same lines as Rob's question, can you just `GET` any 1 of the .dat files. If you can list the directory contents and you can `GET` any 1 of the files, you can dynamically build a script to use `GET` for all of the .dat files. If you can't do either, you don't have appropriate rights on the FTP server.

Comment: I CAN list the files, and I can get individual files too. It just doesnt like *'s. How would I do that dynamic thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute your script file with ftp, you have to turn off the globbing which will allow the use of wildcards in the script. For example:

```
ftp -n -i -s:scriptfile.txt
```

should work but

```
ftp -n -i -g -s:scriptfile.txt
```

will not.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem - he states that mget still doesn't work even from command line, not in a script.

Answer (score 6):

That is by design. The most recent update to the FTP specification (RFC 3659) explicitly forbids it (see section 2.2.2):

```
For the commands defined in this specification, all pathnames are to be treated literally. That is, for a pathname given as a parameter to a command, the file whose name is identical to the pathname given is implied. No characters from the pathname may be treated as special or "magic", thus no pattern matching (other than for exact equality) between the pathname given and the files present in the NVFS of the server-FTP is permitted.

Clients that desire some form of pattern matching functionality must obtain a listing of the relevant directory, or directories, and implement their own file name selection procedures.
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but it might help someone.  I had the same issue with wildcards on MGET from Windows FTP, but it was not consistent in that it worked talking to *some* remote systems, but not to *all* of them.

My script was doing this:

```
cd /folder/folder
mget ./-400TA/folder/*_XYZ
```

In the folder structure I have a set of different folders that begin with hyphens, and for whatever reason the script CD's down to just above there, and uses the relative path in the MGET.  I had the same issue that some of you reported, that if I connected interactively and typed the commands one by one, it worked.  But in batch, it didn't.

I followed the suggestions in this and other posts, but no joy.  I don't have access to the remote systems at the moment to look at them to figure out why some worked and some didn't.

However, what I did find was this.  Changing my script as follows:

```
cd /folder/folder/-400TA/folder
mget *_XYZ
```

did the trick.  Simple.  There's some strange interaction going on somewhere possibly with folder protections or something, but it just shows that trying out different things may get you there in the end.

Comment: I'm doing this, but I find that it only pulls in one file, not all the matching files.

Answer (score 1):

It could very well also be a firewall issue where it is not permitting or forwarding the servers inbound connection. Happened to me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a rather unlikely speculation - especially since the asker of the question has already accepted a different answer. SO is not a discussion forum - even if it seems that way sometimes. And we try to keep answers strictly on-topic of the question. This could have been a comment to the question (if there wasn't yet an accepted answer). Once you have more reputation you'll be able to comment on other people's post. Until then please focus on asking good questions and providing good answers with added value to the question. See the help page. Cheers!

Comment: I had the exact same error and it was caused by the firewall - how is this not an answer? Isn't it more useful to have have all the answers for a specific question under a single question?

Comment: Yes it is. If they answer the question. Imho this particular Q&A pair is a borderline case. As a rule of thumb I would be cautious adding an answer if there's already an accepted answer. Here, the author already commented explicitly that he can get individual files. So your answer is obviously not solving this particular problem. We can argue that the question is poorly phrased, or that the comments possibly should be edits to the question.

Comment: FYI, I could get individual files too! My intention was to extend the topic so it is useful for others having the same question. If this is something that is not desired in SO than I can remove or convert it to a comment

Comment: I don't see how a firewall rule would allow me to get one file but not multiples.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, `mget` requires both a source and destination.  So,

```
mget *.dat .
```

, should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure glob is on, when turned off the file name in the put and get commands is taken literally and wildcards will not be looked at.

More info:

> glob:Toggle filename expansion for mdelete, mget and mput. If globbing
>   is turned off with glob, the file name arguments are taken literally
>   and not expanded. Globbing for mput is done as in csh. For mdelete and
>   mget, each remote file name is expanded separately on the remote
>   machine and the lists are not merged. Expansion of a directory name is
>   likely to be different from expansion of the name of an ordinary file:
>   the exact result depends on the foreign operating system and ftp
>   server, and can be previewed by doing ‘mls remote-files -’ Note: mget
>   and mput are not meant to transfer entire directory subtrees of files.
>   That can be done by transferring a tar archive of the subtree (in
>   binary mode).

Once you are inside your ftp try to check the glob and set it on if it is off. The default behaviour is on, from the command line when connecting to ftp with the option `-g` you can turn off the file name globbing.