# FTP batch file to get csv files

Tags: csv, batch-file, ftp, get

I am trying to write a .bat file to grab two log files from an ftp server that is associated with a production machine.  I have a couple problems:

1) Using mget command returns "unknown command".  Is it possible that the ftp server does not support this command?

2) When I use a get command to get one of the files, it says command successful and that it transferred ##KB of data.  However, the files do not appear in my local directory that I set nor anywhere else on my computer.

Below is my code:

```
Set FTPServerName=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Set UserName=anonymous
Set Password=
Set LocalFolder=C:\temp
Set RemoteFolder=/logs/historic
Set Filename=*.csv
Set ScriptFile=ftp1

:: Create script

 >"%ScriptFile%" Echo open %FTPServerName%
>>"%ScriptFile%" Echo %UserName%
>>"%ScriptFile%" Echo %Password%
>>"%ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %LocalFolder%
>>"%ScriptFile%" Echo cd %RemoteFolder%
>>"%ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%ScriptFile%" Echo prompt
>>"%ScriptFile%" Echo get %Filename%
>>"%ScriptFile%" Echo quit

:: Run script

ftp -s:"%ScriptFile%"
Del "%ScriptFile%
```

This should grab the first .csv file in the folder /logs/historic and put it in the folder C:\Temp.  If I can get "mget" to work that would be ideal but the way the ftp is set up I'm not sure that it is possible.

Thanks for any help you can provide, and if you need more info I can do my best to provide you with that.  Thanks again!

EDIT/UPDATE: I tried turning globbing off and it actually recognized mget as a command now, but still no files are transferred.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt9SC.png) is what cmd prompt returns now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch FTP mget command not working with wildcard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526350/batch-ftp-mget-command-not-working-with-wildcard)

Comment: Show us your code for `mget` (`get` does not support wildcards). Show us also an exact copy (or screenshot) of the script output.

Comment: Hi Martin, I was not aware that get does not support wildcards! Thanks for that! The code when I use mget is the same except I just substitute mget for get.  [Here](http://i.imgur.com/2b4N4FN.png) is a screenshot of the mget output in cmd.